# Assets Unable to Connect to S3: Access denied by target host

Tags: assets, s3

I'm getting an "Access denied by target host" error when attempting to connect to S3 with Assets.

In order to troubleshoot further, I've added a var_dump around line 238 in third_party/assets/sources/s3/lib/S3.php:

```
        if ($rest->error !== false)
        {
            self::__triggerError(sprintf("S3::listBuckets(): [%s] %s", $rest->error['code'],
                $rest->error['message']), __FILE__, __LINE__);

                var_dump($rest);

            return false;
        }
```

When attempting to refresh the bucket list in Assets via the EE control panel, I can now see the details of the error:

```
object(stdClass)#162 (3) { ["error"]=> array(2) { ["code"]=> string(12) "AccessDenied" ["message"]=> string(13) "Access Denied" } ["code"]=> int(403) ["headers"]=> array(1) { ["type"]=> string(15) "application/xml" } } Access denied by target host.
```

Summary: Amazon's response is "Access Denied"

I thought my credentials may have been to blame, but, editing either key changed the error message, so, that wasn't the problem in this instance.

Using the OS X file transfer app Transmit, I was able to connect to S3 with the same credentials, list files, upload a file, and then view it via the publicly accessible URL, so that ruled out configuration/policy issues on Amazon's end.

Upon further testing with Transmit, I found that I could get the same "Access Denied" error if I omitted the "path" (which is the same thing as the bucket name) setting  when I attempted to connect - it appeared that our policy of not allowing the user to perform a list-buckets command was the problem. Is it possible to hard code the bucket name somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assets recently added support for setting bucket names in config.php, like this:

```
   $config['assets_source_settings'] = array(
      1 => array (
        'access_key_id' => 'key-id-goes-here',
        'secret_access_key' => 'secret-key-goes-here',
        'bucket' => 'bucket-name-goes-here' 
      )
    );
```

That by itself should be sufficient to get past an S3 policy that doesn't allow listing buckets.

Answer (score -1):

I think the issue is perhaps with your server time. It's the solution to the top two Google results for this error at least:

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=449702#

and

[Assets stopped connecting to Amazon S3, Access denied by target host](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/10170/assets-stopped-connecting-to-amazon-s3-access-denied-by-target-host)

Comment: I promise I google before I post ;-)  Per our var_dump, the error is "Access Denied," not the time offset message as described in the other posts.